# USING CASE TO CHANGE PRODUCT NAME

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm working with a table like this:

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+--+--+
| BRAND | PRODUCTNAME | UNITPRICE |  |  |
+-------+-------------+-----------+--+--+
| A     | APEN        |        10 |  |  |
| A     | APENCIL     |        12 |  |  |
| B     | AAPEN       |        15 |  |  |
| B     | AAPENCIL    |         9 |  |  |
| A     | APAPER      |         2 |  |  |
+-------+-------------+-----------+--+--+
```

And I need to find the better price for each product.

I think I need to use CASE and substring to cut the "A" and "AA" before the prodcut name in order to check the best price to the same product. I'm new into this and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Then I just need to use Min(Prodname)??

```
BRAND
,CASE BRAND
        when 'A' then Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTNAME, ' ', ''), '  ', ''),2,22) Prodname
        when 'B' then Substring(REPLACE(REPLACE(PRODUCTNAME, ' ', ''), '  ', ''),3,33) Prodname,
        ELSE 'not known'
        END AS BRANDNAME
,UnitPrice
```

What I need to get with this it's something like:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════╦═══════════╗
║ BRAND ║ PRODUCTNAME ║ UNITPRICE ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╬═══════════╣
║ A     ║ PEN         ║        10 ║
║ B     ║ AAPENCIL    ║         9 ║
║ A     ║ PAPER       ║         2 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE` and MySQL 8+ we can try:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REGEXP_REPLACE(PRODUCTNAME, '^A+', '') ORDER BY UNITPRICE) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    BRAND,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(PRODUCTNAME, '^A+', '') AS PRODUCTNAME,
    UNITPRICE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY UNITPRICE DESC;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The strategy of this query is to do a regex replacemen of `^A+` with empty string, to string off the leading `A` characters from each product name.  This opens up a potentially nasty edge case for products which might legitimately start with capital `A`.  Ignoring this, though, my logic should hold up here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRIM()` function as `TRIM(LEADING 'A' FROM PRODUCTNAME)` to get rid of the leading `A`s :

```
SELECT T1.BRAND, T2.*
  FROM TAB T1
  JOIN (
        SELECT TRIM(LEADING 'A' FROM PRODUCTNAME) AS PRODUCT_NAME,
               MIN(UNITPRICE) AS UNITPRICE
          FROM TAB
         GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME) T2 
     ON TRIM(LEADING 'A' FROM T1.PRODUCTNAME) = T2.PRODUCT_NAME
       AND T1.UNITPRICE = T2.UNITPRICE
  ORDER BY T1.UNITPRICE DESC;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f1f6b6deb518d07f474039c5cf7e5774)</kbd>